# In erlang how do I unpack a list of tuple in a function argument?

Tags: list, function, tuples, erlang

I have the requirement

```
add_items(AuctionId, [{Item, Desc, Bid}]) -> {ok, [{ItemId, Item]} | {error, unknown_auction}.
```

How do I use the list of tuples to write my function body?

What I've tried:

```
add_items(AuctionId, ItemList) -> ...
```

This works fine, but I haven't matched the requirement - but the requirement returns a function_clause error if I define it that way as it cannot be pattern-matched (and I don't think the question wants me to define the specification this way either as I would write something like

```
-spec add_items(reference(), [item_info()]) -> 
{ok, [{itemid(), nonempty_string()}]} | {error, unknown_auction()}.
```

It also does not match say trying to do a recursion definition with a head and a tail ala [] and [H|T]

Comment: You should edit your question considering that the one who will read it have no idea of what you intend to do. Be clear, complete and concise.

Comment: @Pascal all I want to do is access the argument and I think the function clause head might be misspecified so what I want to do with it afterwards is irrelevant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you can do:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

%%add_items(AuctionId, [{Item, Desc, Bid}]) -> 
                     {ok, [{ItemId, Item]} | {error, unknown_auction}.

add_items(AuctionId, Items) ->
    case valid_auction(AuctionId) of
        true -> insert_items(Items, _Results=[]);
        false -> {error, unknown_auction}
    end.

%% Here you should check the db to see if the AuctionId exists:
valid_auction(AuctionId) ->
    ValidAuctionIds = sets:from_list([1, 2, 3]),
    sets:is_element(AuctionId, ValidAuctionIds).

%% Here's a recursive function that pattern matches the tuples in the list:
insert_items([ {Item, Desc, Bid} | Items], Acc) ->
    %%Insert Item in the db here:
    io:format("~w, ~w, ~w~n", [Item, Desc, Bid]),
    ItemId = from_db,
    insert_items(Items, [{ItemId, Item} | Acc]);
insert_items([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

In the shell:

```
8> c(a).                                
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

9> a:add_items(4, [{apple, fruit, 10}]).
{error,unknown_auction}

10> a:add_items(1, [{apple, fruit, 10}, {cards, game, 1}]).
apple, fruit, 10
cards, game, 1
[{from_db,apple},{from_db,cards}]

11>
```

The shell interaction demonstrates that `add_items()` satisfies your requirement:

1. It takes two arguments, with the second argument being a list whose elements are three element tuples.
2. The return value is either an `ok` tuple containing a list of two element tuples; or the tuple  `{error,unknown_auction}`.